# Question in Stephan's TUGboat article about \expandafter

Tags: expandafter, tugboat

In the first page of Stephan Bechtolshein's [TUGboat article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf) about `\expandafter`, he described the rules of the execution of `\expandafter`.

I think the case iii should not be listed here since the opening curly brace should be token<sub>e</sub> rather than token<sub>1</sub>. That's to say, the author should have put iii in the outermost step 1. Am I right?
[image]

Comment: well something is wrong, the referenced example 8 has token_e `{` and token_1 `\the`, but actually the whole description is somewhat flawed as it implies the only expandable primitives are `\expandafter`, `\csname` and `\the` which isn't right.

Comment: Thank you@DavidCarlisle. Someone recommended reading this article in this site so I had a try several days ago. But I found there might be some problems in the article so I asked here.

Comment: @Stephen If token_1 is {, nothing interesting happens.  If  token_e is {, there is no “suspension”, as no particular rule applies.

Comment: @egreg, token_e is `{` can be used in, for example, `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral3}`. The `{` is suspended so that `\romannumeral3` can be expanded into `iii`. Is this right?

Comment: @Stephen I believe it's better to think It isn't executed/expanded until the expansion of the next token has been performed, just like every other token following `\expandafter`.

Comment: so essentially `{` after `\expandafter` has nothing special

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the tutorial isn't very precise. Actually, point 2.iii is completely wrong: if ⟨token<sub>1</sub>⟩ is `{`, then it simply isn't expanded, because no character token is expandable.

But item 2. is generally wrong under many respects. Other primitives are expandable, not only `\expandafter`, `\csname` and `\the`. For instance, all *conditionals* are expandable, including `\else`, `\fi` and `\or` among them. This is the feature that makes possible to do

```
⟨primitive if⟩⟨condition⟩
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{⟨first⟩}{⟨second⟩}%
```

which is a very useful piece of code that Bechtolsheim seems to ignore (as far as I remember, it's not even described in his four volume book on TeX). Also `\number` is expandable, just to mention another primitive.

It's much simpler: when TeX is expanding tokens (that is, always, unless expansion is being suppressed, such as when reading the replacement text in a macro definition with `\def`) and finds `\expandafter`, it jumps over the next token, let's call it ⟨token<sub>*e*</sub>⟩, and tries to expand the following one. If the token is expandable, it is replaced by its expansion (possibly with lookup for arguments). The expansion of `\expandafter` is void and the process restarts from ⟨token<sub>*e*</sub>⟩ which will be either expanded (if it is expandable) or executed.

No difference at all when ⟨token<sub>*e*</sub>⟩ is `{` with respect to every possible other token.

Also example 8 is a bit misleading, because it skips over a fundamental feature, namely that in the assignment to a token register, the (optional) `=` can be followed by a ⟨filler⟩, which means that TeX will expand tokens ignoring space and `\relax` tokens until finding `{`. This makes it possible to do

```
\tb=\expandafter{\the\ta}
```

Possibly *minutiae*. My opinion is that either the rule above is mentioned or the case should not be treated as an example, but as a feature on its own.